# Livewire Pagination not showing data when move to next page

Tags: laravel, pagination, laravel-livewire

i have a problem with `laravel-livewire` pagination.

[image]

in the picture above is my first page and fine. but after moving to page 2 or other pages, it will be like this

[image]

the table not showing anything. here is my code

```
use WithPagination;

    public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.stock-opname.table-barang', ['barangs' => $this->barangs]);
    }


    public function reloadTable($merkId, $supplierId, $kategoriId, $tanggal)
    {
        $this->reset(['hargaPokokStock', 'hargaJualStock']);
        $this->tanggal = $tanggal;
        $br = Barang::with('supplier', 'merk', 'kategori')
            ->when($supplierId, function ($query, $supplierId) {
                $query->where('supplier_id', $supplierId);
            })->when($kategoriId, function ($query, $kategoriId) {
                $query->where('kategori_id', $kategoriId);
            })->when($merkId, function ($query, $merkId) {
                $query->where('merk_id', $merkId);
            })->when($tanggal, function ($query, $tanggal) {
                $startDate = "2023-01-01 00:00:00";
                $endDate = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($tanggal));
                $query->whereBetween('updated_at', [$startDate, $endDate]);
            });

        $brGet = $br->get();
        $this->barangs = $br->paginate(10);
        foreach ($brGet as $barang) {
            $hppStock = $barang->stock * $barang->harga_pokok;
            $hjStock = $barang->stock * $barang->harga_jual;
            $this->hargaPokokStock = $this->hargaPokokStock + $hppStock;
            $this->hargaJualStock = $this->hargaJualStock + $hjStock;
        }
    }
```

anyone know how to solve it ? thanks for the answer